"This function has crashed" - Netlify
I am getting this error after successful build on Netlify -

Here is my functions log -

Jul 4, 04:29:02 PM: 2024-07-04T10:59:02.459Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find package 'urlpattern-polyfill' imported from /var/task/___netlify-bootstrap.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'urlpattern-polyfill' imported from /var/task/___netlify-bootstrap.mjs","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:404:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:373:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:250:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}
Jul 4, 04:29:02 PM: INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 378.58 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
Jul 4, 04:29:02 PM: Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
Jul 4, 04:29:02 PM: 985bf6ef Duration: 493.11 ms    Memory Usage: 28 MB
Jul 4, 04:29:03 PM: 2024-07-04T10:59:03.936Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find package 'urlpattern-polyfill' imported from /var/task/___netlify-bootstrap.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'urlpattern-polyfill' imported from /var/task/___netlify-bootstrap.mjs","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:404:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:373:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:250:38)","    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}
Jul 4, 04:29:03 PM: INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 385.20 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
Jul 4, 04:29:04 PM: Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
Jul 4, 04:29:04 PM: 9ac48e61 Duration: 482.16 ms    Memory Usage: 28 MB


It says, I need to install a package - urlpattern-pollyfills. I am not using this package anywhere in my app and then I still install it here is my package.json.
package.json

{
  "name": "report-management",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.1",
    "@emotion/server": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.14.3",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.138",
    "@mui/material": "5.14.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "@tabler/icons-react": "2.30.0",
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "apexcharts": "^3.43.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie": "^0.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.2",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.12",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-apexcharts": "1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-helmet-async": "1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "react-top-loading-bar": "^2.3.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "urlpattern-polyfill": "^10.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.13",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}



I don't know what is causing this error, your suggestion and help is really appreciated. Thank you.
I tried searching on netlify forms and their are people facing similar issue but with a proper error message not like mine. So I am unsure what it means.
